# windows form does not paint full region

Tags: c#, winforms

I’m making a card game and I’m trying to use a paint event handler to paint a card onto the form. I’ve noticed that if I override OnPaint with the same code, although the card is painted immediately when the form is activated, the card is painted correctly. However, when I put the same code into a paint event handler, the card is only half-painted onto the form. Also, if I ‘Hide()’ the form, then ‘Show()’ and ‘Activate()’ it from it’s parent form, the card is displayed properly when the form comes up again:

```
    private void PaintCard(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BegunPlay)
        {
            Region Card = new Region(Animation.CardShape(new Point(550, 300)));
            e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.FloralWhite, Card);
        }
    }
```

Thats the paint event handler that fails to paint the card fully:
Image: 
[half card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSsGR.jpg)

And here’s how the form looks after pressing the ‘back’ button which uses ‘Hide()’ to hide the form, and pressing a button on the parent form to ‘Show()’ and ‘Activate()’ this form:
Image: 
[full card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMy6E.jpg)

I’ve looked around the internet, but I can’t seem to find someone who has the same problem. Can someone please suggest something to try?

Comment: Windows Forms is generally not suited for games. There are dedicated approachs to making games in .NET and .NET Core. A cardgame like Solitaire might just be possible. But you are already meeting the problems with drawing stuff. If your goal is to learn either WindowsForms or Game development this is propably not the right approach.

Comment: Don't use both `OnPaint` and a paint event handler.   `OnPaint` normally raises the paint event.   If `OnPaint` is available use that.  Otherwise use the paint event of the control you are painting on.

Comment: Winforms is supposed to only update and redraw the parts of the form that need redrawing. Does `PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle`correlate to the drawn part?

Comment: Why use regions?  You didn't post enough code for us to reproduce your issue.